# ngTable directive issue with params variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm using [ngTable](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1) directive for a grid.I need to set the page count from my controller.Let's say I need to set the page size as 50.How can I do that? How can I access `params` variable from my controller ?

I have tried like below.But it throws exception where `TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined`

```
$scope.params.count(50);
```

**Html**

```
<button type="button" ng-class="{'active':params.count() == 50}" ng-click="params.count(50)" class="btn btn-default">50</button>
```

**js**

```
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,            // show first page
        count: 10           // count per page
    }, {
        total: data.length, // length of data
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

count is a property, and there is no params variable in your scope but a tableParams... `tableParams.count` looks better

```
 $scope.tableParams.count(50);
```